# Codeception: Safari screenshot is blank only with a few buttons on it but without working area

Tags: php, safari, codeception

Currently using PHP Codeception for frontend testing and integrated it w\ Sikuli to provide pixel comparison.
All Sikuli checks are working like:
1. Taking page screenshot;
2. Matching template w\ Sikuli;

Firefox and Chrome returns dope screenshots of all working area.
Safari only returns a few buttons from DOM but not all page. Screenshot is an example of how it is. Actually i'd like to take screenshot where this blank area is filled by canvas which is presented live but can't be snapped at screenshot. Does anyone faced this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfvQr.png)

Comment: Can you add a `$I->wait()` to wait for the canvas to load?

Comment: Already gave it a try but it's not working. Additionally faced with this on Samsung Galaxy S7 (via BrowserStack).